# Ask nn.MSELoss() calculation mechnism in pytorch framework

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I want to ask that when calculating MSE loss about time-sequence data shaped like (minibatch, feature, sequence length) in pytorch by using `nn.MSELoss()` with `reduction="mean"`,  average just targets on minibatch? or also implicitly about time sequence?

To confirm the calculation result to check what I have questioned above, I printed out below code

```
nn.MSELoss() #reduction='mean' is default
x_t = torch.ones((32, 4, 100)) # [minibatch size, feature size, time sequence length]
x_est = torch.ones((32, 4, 100)) * 2

loss_result = loss(x_t, x_est)
print(loss_result)
```

```
>>> tensor(1.)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`nn.MSELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html) loss computes the L2 distance between the two inputs point-wise. Additionally, the reduction parameter dictates whether to average or sum the resulting tensor, in that case, it will apply the reduction *over all dimensions*. Here is a comparison:

```
>>> x_t = torch.rand((32, 4, 100))
>>> x_est = torch.rand((32, 4, 100))
```

With `nn.MSELoss`:

```
>>> loss(x_t, x_est)
```

With builtin Tensor methods:

```
>>> (x_t-x_est).pow(2).mean()
```

Comment: If you found this answer solved your problem,  consider marking this as correct (green checkmark on the left)